# Ansible + Jinja2 Loop - Dict object has no attribute

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, cisco, asa

I'm losing my mind here but i just cant seem to see where my problem lies! Im trying to have ansible create me users on a Cisco ASA and im using Jinja 2 templates.

I have a host vars file where i am specifying the users (sensitised data):

```yaml
users:
  tom:
    sshkey: "xxxx"
    privilegelevel: 15
  dick:
    sshkey: "xxxx"
    privilegelevel: 15
  harry:
    password: "yyyy"
    privilegelevel: 15
```

My templates for creating the users (users.j2):

```
{% if users is defined %}
{% for user, value in users.items() %}
username {{ value }} privilege {{ value.privilegelevel }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

and if they have an ssh key (users-ssh.j2):

```
{% if users and 'sshkey' is defined %}
{% for user, value in users.items() %}
username {{ value }} privilege {{ value.privilegelevel }}
username {{ value }} attributes
  ssh authentication publickey {{ value.sshkey }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And last but not least the playbook:

```yaml
- name: create users
  asa_config:
    src: templates/users.j2
    provider: "{{ cli }}"
    save: yes
  tags: users

- name: create ssh pubkey auth
  asa_config:
    src: templates/users-ssh.j2
    provider: "{{ cli }}"
    save: yes
  tags: users
```

---

When running the playbook, the user.j2 works fine, but user-ssh.j2 fails with:

```sh
fatal: [HOSTNAME_HERE]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'sshkey'"}
```

When calling the dict values with:

```yaml
- name: Output dict
  debug:
    msg: "User is {{ item.key }} and the ssh key is {{ item.value.sshkey }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', users) }}"
  tags: users
```

It gives me the correct values:

```
ok: [fw01.prd.sc1] => (item={'key': 'tom', 'value': {'sshkey': 'xxxx', 'privilegelevel': 15}}) => {
    "msg": "User is tom and the ssh key is xxxx"
}
ok: [fw01.prd.sc1] => (item={'key': 'dick', 'value': {'sshkey': 'xxxx', 'privilegelevel': 15}}) => {
    "msg": "User is dick and the ssh key is xxxx"
}
```

Can anyone see where i may be going wrong with my J2 templating as ive a fair few things but getting nowhere!

Many thanks in advance :)

Kris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This loop...

```
{% if users and 'sshkey' is defined %}
{% for user, value in users.items() %}
username {{ value }} privilege {{ value.privilegelevel }}
username {{ value }} attributes
  ssh authentication publickey {{ value.sshkey }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

...doesn't check if a user has an `sshkey` attribute. The expression `if users and 'sshkey' is defined` is identical to writing `if users`, because the expression`if 'sshkey' is defined` will always be `true` -- `'sshkey'` is a literal string, not a variable.

Since the loop runs for all users, it fails when you get to `harry`, because `harry` doesn't have an `sshkey` attribute.

You need to filter your users for those that have an `sshkey` attribute, for example by using a loop filtering as described [in the documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for):

```
{% for user, value in users.items() if value.sshkey is defined %}
username {{ user }} privilege {{ value.privilegelevel }}
username {{ user }} attributes
  ssh authentication publickey {{ value.sshkey }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that I've also replaced `username {{ value }}` with `username {{ user }}`, because I'm reasonably sure the former was not what you meant.

---

For example, this playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    users:
      tom:
        sshkey: "xxxx"
        privilegelevel: 15
      dick:
        sshkey: "xxxx"
        privilegelevel: 15
      harry:
        password: "yyyy"
        privilegelevel: 15

  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: users.txt
        content: |
          {% for user, value in users.items() if value.sshkey is defined %}
          username {{ user }} privilege {{ value.privilegelevel }}
          username {{ user }} attributes
            ssh authentication publickey {{ value.sshkey }}
          {% endfor %}
```

Produces as output in `users.txt`:

```
username tom privilege 15
username tom attributes
  ssh authentication publickey xxxx
username dick privilege 15
username dick attributes
  ssh authentication publickey xxxx
```

Comment: That is indeed what i meant when i put {{ value }}! 

Well would you look at that, that makes so much more sense now. Helps out with a few other playbooks as well :D many thanks for this larsks!